# Exception while constructing BeanInfo using java.beans.Introspector

Tags: java, introspection

`Introspector.getBeanInfo` throws `java.beans.IntrospectionException` when trying to get `BeanInfo` for a class that specializes return type of indexed getter method in sub-class.

Example code:

```
import java.beans.*;

public class IntrospectorIssue {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            final BeanInfo beanInfo = Introspector.getBeanInfo(TestClass.class);
        } catch (IntrospectionException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public static abstract class AbstractTestClass {

        public Number getValue(int i) {
            return null;
        }

        public void setValue(int i, Number value) {

        }
    }

    public static class TestClass extends AbstractTestClass {

        public Long getValue(int i) { // (1)
            return null;
        }

        public void setValue(int i, Number value) { //(2)

        }

    }
}
```

The exception is thrown by `java.beans.IndexedPropertyDescriptor` which expects that
return type of (1) Long should be equal to (2) Number.

I'm using 1.7.0_45-b18 64-Bit JDK

The exception is not thrown if I change return type of (1) to Number.
It seems like a bug in JDK and I have found similar bug report with a fix for `java.beans.PropertyDescriptor` (http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u-dev/jdk/rev/ef26b6c8264d).

Posting here just to double-check if I haven't missed something.